# How to return data from abstract method while in main

Tags: java

I am trying to get the main program to reflect the data (Area and Perimeter) returned in the abstract method in the triangle subclass. No matter what I try, it always prints "0.0".

Any pointers on how I can get it to print the Area and Perimeter?

Main:

```
public class MainExecute {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle Shape01 = new Triangle (4,6);
        Square Shape02 = new Square (5);
        Trapezoid Shape03 = new Trapezoid (4,3,6);
        Shape01.printTriangle();
        Shape02.printSquare();
        Shape03.printTrapezoid();
    }
}
```

Shape abstract Class:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract double getPerimeter ();
    public abstract double getArea ();

    public double Perimeter;
    public double Area;
}
```

Triangle subclass:

```
public class Triangle extends Shape{
    @Override
    public double getPerimeter (){
        double triPem;
        triPem = ((Math.sqrt(((this.base / 2)* (this.base / 2)) + (this.height * this.height))) * 2) + this.base;
        return triPem;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea (){
        Area = (base * height) / 2;
        return Area;
    }

    public double base;
    public double height;

    public double getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(double base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Triangle (double base, double height){
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void printTriangle(){
        System.out.println("The perimeter of this shape is " + Perimeter);
        System.out.println("The Area of this shape is " + Area);
    }        
}
```

Comment: There are really far too many things wrong with this, for anyone to give you a good, short answer.  I would suggest re-reading the sections on inheritance and polymorphism in the Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not perform your calculation before print.

If you call the valid method that caulculate first then you will have proper result

```
Shape01.getPerimeter();
Shape01.getArea ();
Shape01.printTriangle();
```

Note:

you should also look at two other things:

The variable like `Shape01` `Area` etc. should not start with capital letter. In Java the variables are in [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

The second is the design of your abstract class.

fields

public double Perimeter;
public double Area;

accessors

public abstract double getPerimeter ();
public abstract double getArea ();

When you design a abstract class you create a contract that will work in any case equally. In this case you break it because to initialize the values for fields you must call perform some operation. To improve your design remove those fields from abstract class and replace the occurrence with method call. This will assure that result is always up to date. And prevent problem that you have now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public void printTriangle(){
    System.out.println("The perimeter of this shape is " + getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("The Area of this shape is " + getArea());
}
```

then you can also drop the

```
public double Perimeter;
public double Area;
```

since you recalculate them every time.

Another possibility is calculating `Perimeter` and `Area` in the constructor of `Triangle`, then your other code would work too - and it would only be calculated once.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I didn't know it was that simple, just a little tweak in the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't ever set up `Perimeter` or `Area`.

`getArea` sets `Area`, but it never gets called.

My suggestion is to remove these variables completely and just use `getPerimeter` and `getArea`.

If you want to keep these variables, it's advised to make `base` and `height` private so external classes can't modify them directly (which would obviously change the perimeter and area, but they won't automatically get recalculated), and put code to update the perimeter and area in `setBase` and `setHeight` and the constructor. Then you'd also need to make `Perimeter` and `Area` private so *these* aren't modified externally. Then you need `get` functions to return them, and then an `update` function to update them (which would look similar to your current `get` functions). Quite an extended process, which is why I simply suggested removing them.

Answer (score 0):

> No matter what I try, it always prints "0.0"

thats because you have not initialized them nor have you assigned some value before using them. As a result they are assigned default value of `0.00`

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
System.out.println("The perimeter of this shape is " + getPerimeter());
System.out.println("The area of this shape is " + getArea());
```